# Print service response in an array

Tags: angular, api, response

In have below service response in postman. I have write service for get the response for my angular app.
This is my service

```js
getSessions() {
  return this.http.get(
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sessions/all/', 
    {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization' : 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('userTokens')
      }),
    }
  );
}
```

This is my home.component.ts

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.authService.getSessions().subscribe((data : any) => {
    this.Sessions = data;
    console.log(this.Sessions);
  });
}
```

I can get the response. below is my response.

```json
{
    "status_code": 200,
    "message": "Successfully retrieved healing session",
    "result": {
        "1": {
            "title": "Test session",
            "description": "this is a test session",
            "price": "10.00",
            "image": null,
            "pk": 1,
            "product": 1,
            "instructor": 4,
            "healing_type": "Biofeedback",
            "m_group_id": "0"
        },
        "2": {
            "title": "api test",
            "description": "this is a test",
            "price": "5.50",
            "image": null,
            "pk": 2,
            "product": 2,
            "instructor": 4,
            "healing_type": "Nutritionist",
            "m_group_id": "0"
        },
        "3": {
            "title": "api test4",
            "description": "this is a test4",
            "price": "50.50",
            "image": null,
            "pk": 14,
            "product": 14,
            "instructor": 6,
            "healing_type": "3",
            "m_group_id": "5"
        },
        "4": {
            "title": "api test4",
            "description": "this is a test4",
            "price": "50.50",
            "image": null,
            "pk": 15,
            "product": 15,
            "instructor": 6,
            "healing_type": "3",
            "m_group_id": "5"
        }  
    }
}
```

I want to print this results separately. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried using `Object.values` on the result?

Comment: @Patrick I tried {{Sessions.result}} in my home.component.html. It prints [object object]

Comment: I mean `this.Sessions = Object.values(data.result)`

Comment: {{Sessions.result | json}}  try this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the raw response to HTML please see the below options

**Print raw response to UI:**

```
<p>{{Sessions.results | json}}</p>
```

**Print Formatted response to UI:**

```
<div *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(Sessions.result)">
 <p> {{key}}</p>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{data.result[key].title}}</td>
    <td>{{data.result[key].description}}</td>
    <td>{{data.result[key].price}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```